# how is litecoin different from bitcoin

Tags: blockchain, litecoin

So far, i only know that litecoin is using another mining algorithm called Scrypt which has some ASIC resistance. Is there any more difference? Or they are completely the same except the mining algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Another key difference is the rate at which new blocks are generated. Bitcoin blocks are created every 10 minutes or so. Litecoin blocks are produced every 2.5 minutes. This has implications in terms of security of the coins against double spending.